# Error C3861 during compile

Tags: c++

Hello I'm try to run some OpenGL (freeglut) examples in VS2012 (Ultimate)
Everything is working fine and my draw routine draws what I'm expected, the problem is when I'm trying to add DisplayFPS() in my DrawScene() I'm getting "error C3861: 'DisplayFPS': identifier not found" problem is not in function itself because when I'm calling it from another place everything is ok.
How to fix this error?
Thanks!

---

```
GLvoid DrawScene( GLvoid )
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();

    // draw some geometry here

    glFlush();

    glutSwapBuffers();

    DisplayFPS();
}

void DisplayFPS( void )
{
    // some code here
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about declaring `DisplayFPS` above `DrawScene`:

```
void DisplayFPS( void );  // <- THIS


GLvoid DrawScene( GLvoid )
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();

    // draw some geometry here

    glFlush();

    glutSwapBuffers();

    DisplayFPS();
}

void DisplayFPS( void )
{
    // some code here
}
```